# Reading a sessionStorage property and creating an if statement

Tags: javascript

So, I want to read a value from sessionStorage. I know how to do this, but then I want to do something like this:

```
function whiteSet() {
    if (// condition: what the heck would I put here?) {
        const color = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        //if the value  'theme' is equal to 'aluminum' then:
        document.getElementById("headerbar").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/themes/aluminum.png)";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("headerbar").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/themes/galaxy.png)";
    };
```

I don't really know what to do :/
If an answer already exists for this question, I have already tried finding it and failed.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but if you hover over the down-vote arrow, you will see reasons for down-votes. One is "this question does not show any research effort". Consider adding such information in future posts. Also, the site does not care if a poster is a professional coder or a beginner since it isn't a help site per se but rather a question and answer site, and the quality of the question matters. Beginners can ask good questions, but it's not easy and they need to put much effort in to do so, including showing their research. The [ask] can help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take it step by step.  First you're reading the value out of local storage and putting it in the variable 'color', then you need to decide what to do based on what value you read out.  So instead of starting out with an `if` statement, get `color` first and then the conditional tests against its content:

```
function whiteSet() {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if (theme === "aluminum") {
    document.getElementById("headerbar").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/themes/aluminum.png)";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("headerbar").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/themes/galaxy.png)";
  };
}
```

(Personally, since you're storing it in a localStorage key named "theme", I'd name the variable "theme" too instead of "color" just to avoid confusion; but that's more of a coding style thing than a requirement for it to work.)